# How do i remove the ppc section in growl framework?

Tags: cocoa, app-store, powerpc, growl

Now i add growl notification support into my app ,when i submitted it to mac app store with organizer,it says that 
"
Unsupported Architecture - Application executables may support either or both of the Intel architectures:

i386 (32-bit)
x86_64 (64-bit)
"
Finally i find that its issue by growl library, so i need to remove the ppc section in growl,so,how to?
Please help..

Comment: 1.2.2 will be the last version of the framework to include PowerPC support for this reason. We'll drop it in 1.3. http://code.google.com/p/growl/issues/detail?id=191

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `lipo` command line utility, which strips architectures off fat binaries (what an appropriate name). First, check which architectures there are in your Growl framework:

```
$ lipo -info path/to/Growl.framework/Growl
Architectures in the fat file: Growl are: x86_64 i386 ppc
```

In this case, we simply have `ppc`, but there are about 10 variants (of which I've met 3). To avoid any surprise, you should run this command any time you want to strip architectures from a file instead of just jumping to the removal part. (If you're curious, [`man 3 arch`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arch.3.html) has the exhaustive list of possible architectures for fat binaries on Mac OS.)

Then, remove the `ppc` achitecture:

```
$ lipo -remove ppc path/to/Growl.framework/Growl -output GrowlIntel
```

Find the real Growl binary (should be under Versions somewhere) and replace it with GrowlIntel.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "ditto". I submitted my last Mac app with frameworks included that are stripped off ppc support using the two below commands. No rejections from Apple.

```
$ ditto -rsrc --arch i386 --arch x86_64 Growl-WithInstaller Growl-WithInstaller_noppc
$ lipo -info Growl-WithInstaller_noppc
```